# How to find file size of tables where column id = value in postgres/sql

Tags: sql, postgresql

How would I find the total size of tables where the column_id = 'value'?

I have a column which is called 'platform_id' and it is within many tables within my database, but not all of them.

I am trying to figure out how large the tables are that have the platform_id equal to 99

Comment: What do you mean by "size" here? Do you mean a count of the number of rows?

Comment: I mean size as kb/mb  like pg_size_pretty

Comment: So basically you need an obvious variant of [listing the columns in a table](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/22362/how-do-i-list-all-columns-for-a-specified-table/22420) plus some form of [measuring the space used by a table](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/23879/measure-the-size-of-a-postgresql-table-row/23933#23933), applied to each of the tables in those results.

Comment: So, disk use accounting for shards / tenants then?